# how can I link css file in activecollab in a custom module?

Tags: php, module, content-management-system, project, activecollab

I am working on activecollab custom module, so have some problem in css file placement, i placed a file in

```
mymodule\assets\default\stylesheets\frontend\main.css
```

but after installing "mymodule", activecollab not fetching that css file on run time loaded page ..

if anyone did this please help me, is there need to add a line to link that css with module? or css folder issue?

**UPDATED:**

Additionally i want to know what is FRONTEND and BACKEND in assets/default/stylesheets/ folder of module?

is there i need to place my normal main.css file in frontend folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frontend and Backend are contexts in which assets are used:

1. Frontend is public part of the application, that does not require login. It's used to serve shared pages, public request forms etc
2. Backend is everything behind login screen (basically, activeCollab's main interface)

My guess, based on your description, is that you are placing your stylesheets into a wrong context. Try backend, instead of frontend.

Comment: i tried to copy stylesheets into backend folder as well but it never detects, I guess need to add some line of code to pointing stylesheets .. if i have more than one stylesheets, then how activecollab get all stylesheets in project?

Comment: System simply loads all CSS files from folders that are properly named (convention over configuration approach). You either didn't name folders and files right (CSS files need to have .css extension) or you didn't force refresh the page.

Comment: hmm yeh but its is still not grabbing my stylesheets;
I tried again by placing everywhere same main.css file at a same time like this but it couldn't grab any of them:

- mymodule/assets/default/stylesheets/main.css
- mymodule/assets/default/stylesheets/backend/main.css
- mymodule/assets/default/stylesheets/frontend/main.css

any other solution?

Comment: It appears to me that you are experiencing caching problems, not collector problems. Have you tried disabling cache in browser that you use fo development to confirm that you ALWAYS get fresh content? activeCollab's stylesheet collector uses agressive caching (because it's mostly used in production environment), so you should pretty much disable your cache when developing.